# Intercept parsleyjs validation

Tags: parsley.js

I want to delete validation errors generated by PHP (that is server-side) when user triggers any validation.

I can delete previous validation errors when in fact there are new errors using the `errorsContainer` option.
(As on the next example: http://jsfiddle.net/bzydxoL9/)

But I do want to intercept validations always, no matter if valid or invalid ones.

How can I intercept a validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inventive use of `errorsContainer`, but it's really not meant to be used this way.

Listen to the [events](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events) like `field:validate` instead.

Comment: I know, that event is exactly what I was looking for, tnks